# respawn option for bsd rc.d

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd, bsd

I run a small daemon and want it to be respawned when it is killed.  I use "respawn" option in inittab on linux systems.(It is a small embedded platform.).

Now I am trying the same daemon on BSD. I have put my entry in "rc.d". But I could not find respawn option for BSD.

I can write a small program which respawns my daemon. But I was wondering if there must be something already built for BSD to restart killed services.

Do you know anything which I can use.

Thanks

P.S. I know I can do this thing in my daemon itself. But currently I dont have source for it.

Comment: I kinda fixed it for now with my own wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rc.d`/`init.d` startup script convention does not provide for respawning daemons. That's one of the main reasons why alternatives like [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) and [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) have been created. On your embedded system, your best option is probably a small wrapper that monitors your daemon and restarts it when necessary.

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning anything that respawns services; that being said, the BSDs have /etc/ttys which works very similarly to /etc/inittab, you can just use that.

Comment: Also, there are a number of things in ports which may help. One is sysutils/fsc and another is sysutils/daemontools53. I'm sure there are others if you look around.